# cannot get textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to retrieve the textbox value in javascript. Simple, but it doesn't work for me, as it returns null/undefined as output. The code:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID = "lbl1" 
    ClientIDMode = "Static" 
    runat = "server"    
    Text = "http://test/test1/dilse.mp4" 
    Visible = "false">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button  
    ID = "btnValidate" 
    runat = "server" 
    Text = "Get Values"   
    OnClientClick = "sourceval(); 
/>
```

Javascript:

```
var source = document.getElementById('lbl1').innerHTML;
function sourceval() 
{
    alert(source); 
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your javascript? It may be that the textbox doesn't exist fully at the time of your calls to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're not able to get the value of the textbox because you have Visible="false", because of that the textbox doesn't get rendered when the page loads, you could use a HiddenField instead of textbox

```
<asp:HiddenField ID ="lbl1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value="http://test/test1/dilse.mp4" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.value` property for textboxes.  The code for setting OnClientClick is for VB.  Use '+' instead of '&' if using C#.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Get Values"
         OnClientClick='<%= "sourceval(" & lbl1.ClientID & " );"%>' />
```

Javascript code:

```
    function sourceval(controlId) {
          var source = document.getElementById('lbl1').value;
          alert(source); 
    }
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply. i used .value but it says undefined in my output.

Comment: Try passing in source as a parameter?

Comment: I just saw the problem -- you're using webforms, which autogenerates random IDs based on html element structure.  I will update my code sample

Comment: Updated.  Let me know if it works--- I can't remember if the page will know that ID at runtime, but I assume it would.

Comment: hi, its works now as i have changed the textbox to hiddenfield as Juan  C Suggested,thanks for your time

Comment: yup, I completely overlooked the visible property, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
var source = document.getElementById('lbl1').value;
```